# Error in overriding onCreateView() method

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am trying to link my fragment file named "top_section_fragment" with the java class but I am getting an error while overriding onCreateView() method.Error says "can not resolve symbol R" please help me to fix it.

```
  package com.example.abdulrafay.myapplication;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;


  public class topsectionfragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment,container,false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to import it, click Alt + Enter and select import class

Comment: it probably missing Your R.java file.. look for your log and check where is error? probable it would be on one of your xml file.. resolve it and then clean and rebuild it..

Comment: try cleaning your project

Comment: Easiest way to fix this and every problem would be to ditch Eclipse for Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the import:

```
import com.example.abdulrafay.myapplication.R;
```

If it's still not found, it means it wasn't generated.

In this case, you could do: Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: Did you try also cleaning the project? The R file is not generated if there's also some other errors on your project. Check the logs of Android Studio.

Comment: Build -> Clean project. Please, check this: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html